# Why does tf.assign() slow the execution time?

Tags: tensorflow

Today I add a learning rate decay to my LSTM in Tensorflow.

I change

```
train_op = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(lr_rate).minimize(loss)
```

to

```
lr = tf.Variable(0.0,trainable=False)
```

and run every train step

```
sess.run(tf.assign(lr, lr_rate*0.9**epoch))
```

However, this change increases the execution time from ~7 minutes to over ~20 minutes.

My question is:
Why does this change increase the execution time?

An obvious work-around is to do the assignment only every 1000 iterations. However, I'd like to understand the reasoning behind this.

- Does sess.run() take extra time?
- Does tf.asign() take extra time?
- Could I implement this tf.assign() in another, more efficient, way?

Answer (score 11):

The problem you have has nothing to do with `sess.run` or `tf.assign`. This is a very popular issue in many models and your model is slow because of your bloated graph. I will explain what all of this mean on a very simple example that has nothing to do with your code. Take a look at these 2 snippets:

**Snippet 1**

```
a = tf.Variable(1, name='a')
b = tf.Variable(2, name='b')
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for _ in range(3):
        print sess.run(tf.add(a, b)),
```

**Snippet 2**

```
a = tf.Variable(1, name='a')
b = tf.Variable(2, name='b')
res = tf.add(a, b)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for _ in range(3):
        print sess.run(res),
```

---

Both of them return the same values and looks like they both do the same stuff. The problem is that they create different graphs and if you will `print len(tf.get_default_graph().get_operations())` after the loop, you will see that Snippet 1 has more nodes than Snippet 2. Increase the range to a few thousand and the difference will be significant.

You have the same problem with a bloated graph. Because in each iteration of the loop you create `tf.assign(lr, lr_rate*0.9**epoch)` 3 nodes in the graph. Move your graph definition separately from the graph run and you will see the improvement.

Comment: Nice explanation, Bloated Graph, can be a severe problem when you are updating learning rates after every global step.

Answer (score 3):

An increase of computation time by 3 seems a bit odd but here are some things you can try:

- create an op in the graph to update your learning rate. In your code, you create a new operation at each step, which is added to the graph so it might take extra time. In general, it's best practice to create all the necessary operations before the `tf.Session()`

```py
update_lr = tf.assign(lr, lr_rate*0.9**epoch)
```

- use only 1 `sess.run()` at each iteration, combining training op and `update_lr`

```py
sess.run([train_op, update_lr], ...)
```

- the more efficient way to implement a decayed learning rate is to use [`tf.train.exponential_decay()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/train.html#exponential_decay). If you want to decay by 0.9 every epoch, you can do:

```py
training_size = 60000  # size of an epoch
global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
starter_learning_rate = 0.1
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(starter_learning_rate, global_step,
                                           training_size, 0.9, staircase=True)
# Passing global_step to minimize() will increment it at each step.

train_op = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(lr_rate).minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
```

Comment: Thanks Olivier, I'll implement the exponential_decay(). By the end of the week I'll report the improvements

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure why this could slow down the process this much (in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1439 it seems constantly creating new graph nodes can cause this), I think it is better to use feed_dict to do this:

```
learn_rate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[])
optiizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learn_rate)
...
learnrate = 1e-5
...
sess.run(minimizer, feed_dict={learn_rate: learnrate})
```

I use this approach and I see no performance issue. Moreover, you can pass an arbitrary number, so you can even increase/decrease learning rate based on error on train/validation data.